# How to execute a query which uses multiple database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlconnection

I am developing an ASP.Net website. I have to execute a query which fetches data from two different database.

I have two SqlConnection objects for these connections.

I have both the connections open. But in SqlCommand object, I can specify just one SqlConnection object.

```
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx1;User ID=web_writeonly;Password=aaa;Network Library=DBMSSOCN");
     SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx2;User ID=randomUser;Password=bbb;Network Library=DBMSSOCN");

       conn.open();

       conn1.open();

       SqlCommand cmdUserInfo = new SqlCommand("<query goes here>", conn);
    cmdUserInfo.Parameters.Add("@ifa", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ifacode;
    SqlDataAdapter sdaUserInfo = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdUserInfo);
    sdaUserInfo.Fill(dtSummaryTbl);

    conn.Close();
    conn1.Close();
```

When I execute this code snippet, I get an error "The SELECT permission was denied on the object '***', database 'xxx2', schema 'dbo'."

Please help me out in sorting this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Which part of the error message do you not understand?

Comment: hi - that's because you cannot use a query across two databases ... you have to fetch your data from one then the other - and the error message don't say your code is wrong but your User (I guess **web_writeonly** says **no read**) may not query data ....

Comment: SqlCommand cmdUserInfo = ... you are passing "conn" which is pointing to xxx1. But in the error message you have mentioned xxx2 .. ? :)

Comment: Maybe it's best to break up the query or use stored procs and pass data from one to the other. What is the actual SQL you're trying to execute?

Comment: @Sandeep - Yes I'm passing "conn", but in my query I'm using tables from both the databases. xxx1 objects are working fine, because I've explicitly passed "conn". But since I could not associate the connection string for xxx2 database (conn1), I'm getting the error.

Comment: All I want to ask is: Is there any way I can do this in a single query/stored procedure? Or will I have to write 2 separate queries for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means that you don't have sufficient permissions... check what sql login your website is associated with and then the permissions on the table you're trying to select data from.

Also, on closer inspection, one of your usernames is "web_**writeonly**"... kind of a hint if you're trying to do a select!!! ;)

Comment: Nathan, web_writeonly is the username for xxx1 database, whose connection object (conn) I'm already passing to the SqlCommand object. But the error is for xxx2 database.

Comment: You need one command object per database and the code above doesn't use the connection for xxx2, are you trying to query xxx2 in the sql for the connection to xxx?  If so, then the permission error makes sense: the connection to xxx won't have the necessary security permissions to access xxx2.  Having a procedure that exists on xxx but which references xxx2 is probably the way to go.  (keeps your code simpler too)

Comment: xxx2 still needs to have permissions defined for the user in xxx to perform the necessary select

Comment: Thanks all for answering. I created a new user and gave it sufficient permissions for xxx2 database, and added its credentials to the connection string. It is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your databases are on the same server why can't you just put your SQL into a stored procedure on one of the databases. I am pretty sure you can then just use one connection object and execute your stored procedure which gets data from two databases.

Comment: The databases are on the same server. I'll try creating a procedure. Thanks!

Comment: simply because it's not possible to execute one command on two databases. I am not 100% sure but when you think about it, Sql command is on one database but you try to refer to another one without associating a connection with it even if the second connection is open it's in no way related to the command you're executing.

Comment: I'm getting the same error when executing a procedure which accesses two databases.

Comment: Now it looks like a permissions issue to me. Can you try doing one select at a time and see which one does not have the right permissions. Once you find the user go to SQL Management studio Security and give that user db_owner access to the database.